# Как добавить passive к addEventListener в JQuery библиотеке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

PageSpeed ругается на
`"Пассивные прослушиватели событий не используются для улучшения производительности при прокрутке. Чтобы повысить производительность при прокрутке страницы, используйте флаг 'passive' для прослушивателей событий прикосновения и колеса мыши."`
Указывает на …jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:1:41540
Это `t.addEventListener&&t.addEventListener(d,a)),` в библиотеке.

Пробовал так `t.addEventListener&&t.addEventListener(d,a,{passive:true})),` ругаться перестаёт, но ломается перетаскивание в слайдерах.

Ссылка на пример, который даёт гугл - https://web.dev/uses-passive-event-listeners/